# Linux Privilege Escalation

Tags: linux, bash

I've been trying to solve a box. I got into the box by exploiting a web app and got reverse shell so I was `www-data`. I then found an ssh key that I used to login as another user and I ran `sudo -l` which showed me which files I could run as root.

I'm struggling with what to do to use this to my advantage.

[image: results from sudo -l]

[image: Asks for password when running sudo?]

Comment: Alter server.py to spawn a shell, run it with sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what server.py does, I would suggest performing the following checks:

### Do you have write privileges on server.py?

If so, simply edit it to spawn a bash shell as mentioned by ThoriumBR.

### Do you have write privileges on python library path?

Usually they are in `/usr/lib/python*`. If for some reason the directory is **writable** and server.py **import** modules such as os, you can edit the module to include reverse shell commands.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried running python using sudo but then it asks for the password? it says NOPASSWD for python, what the hell is going on?

Comment: I think you should start by gaining a better understanding of how sudo works, and how the shell in general works on Linux. `man sudo` and `man sudo.conf` is great starting point

Comment: ```sudo -l``` says you can only run the specific command as root with no password:
```/usr/bin/python /home/octopus/webapp/server.py```. It didn't say you can run python as root. If there isn't much you can do with server.py, i would suggest you move on and enumerate other things.

Comment: Thanks for the help @suppko helped me out lots